# how to disable a button permanently after clicking it in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, jsp

how to disable a button permanently after clicking it ?it should remain disabled after refreshing the page also.But after refreshing the page the button is enabled again.how to do this??

Comment: I'm sorry but your question doesn't make sense, permanently disabled then remain disabled after refresh then after refresh it is enabled again?!!, please clarify and help people help you

Comment: You have two way, if you need disable for all user use database, if just for user you can use cookie.

Comment: @SaymoinSam I believe you read the question to fast. OP's description is clear. When the user clicked the button it shall be disabled and remain disabled after a page refresh, but currently when the OP refresh the page the button is enabled again.

Comment: sorry but i don't get you either, you said *"When the user clicked the button"* and then you say, *"when the OP refresh the page"*?! is the OP the user or what?!

Comment: @SaymoinSam, it has only been misspelled, but the concept is clear.

Comment: sometimes I feel I'm a computer so I need the correct statements of code otherwise I complain :D

Comment: @Simone Rossaini thank you.. but can we do without using database??

Comment: No guda for all peoples no.

Answer (score 1):

its really easy ,  just change disabled property to true..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function disableButton(btn){
            document.getElementById(btn.id).disabled = true;
            alert("Button has been disabled.");
        }
    </script>
```

with HTML it would look smth like this

```
<!--JavaScript - Disable Button after Click using JavaScript Function.-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript - Disable Button after Click using JavaScript Function.</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function disableButton(btn){
                document.getElementById(btn.id).disabled = true;
                alert("Button has been disabled.");
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body style="text-align: center;">
        <h1>JavaScript - Disable Button after Click using JavaScript Function.</h1>
        <p><input type="button" id="btn1" value="Click to disable button." onclick="disableButton(this)"</p>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you !! i think this code is only for disabling the button after clicking it but after refreshing the page the button is enabled again.i want the button to get disabled permanently i.e.,the button should remain disabled even after refreshing the page also..